# No puedo actualizar base de datos SQLite en app Android

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, sqlite

Estoy haciendo una app que lleva el inventario de productos, pidiéndole al usuario solo tres datos: código del producto, descripción y precio. Escribí 4 métodos, uno para registrar nuevo producto, otro para buscar, uno para modificar y otro para eliminar algún producto.

El problema es que cuando selecciono el botón de modificar la app se cierra.

Este es el código de la clase SQLite

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos) {
    BaseDeDatos.execSQL("create table articulos(codigo int primary key, descripcion text, precio real)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos, int i, int il) {

}
}
```

y este es el código de la clase de Java donde esta el método modificar:

```
public void Modificar(View view) {
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    String codigo = et_codigo.getText().toString();
    String descripcion = et_descripcion.getText().toString();
    String precio = et_precio.getText().toString();

    if(!codigo.isEmpty() && !descripcion.isEmpty() && !precio.isEmpty()) {

        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
        registro.put("codigo", codigo);
        registro.put("descripcion", descripcion);
        registro.put("precio", precio);

        int cantidad = BaseDeDatos.update("articulos", registro, "codigo" + codigo, null);
        BaseDeDatos.close();

        if(cantidad == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Artículo modificado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "El artículo no existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debes llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

`et_nombre`, `et_descripcion` y `et_precio` son los `EditText` donde el usuario ingresa los datos.

Y el error que me devuelve android es:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: codigo 123

Comment: Seguro es `+ codigo` y no `, codigo`?

Comment: Esto es incorrecto "codigo" + codigo pero en realidad debes revisar el uso del método update(): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad la forma de actualizar la información es incorrecta:

```
   int cantidad = BaseDeDatos.update("articulos", registro, "codigo" + codigo, null);
```

Debes realizarlo de acuerdo a la descripción del método **[update()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))**:

```
public int update (String table, 
            ContentValues values, 
            String whereClause, 
            String[] whereArgs)
```

Debes realizar el siguiente cambio para actualizar los valores de un registro con determinado valor  en su código:

```
 ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
 registro.put("codigo", codigo);
 registro.put("descripcion", descripcion);
 registro.put("precio", precio);
 int cantidad = BaseDeDatos.update("articulos", registro, "codigo" + " = ?", new String[]{codigo});
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, efectivamente no estaba siguiendo la descripción del método update(); hice la modificación que me indicaste y la app funciona perfectamente. Ya acepte la respuesta